# open folder from terminal's current directory (Linux Debian)

Tags: bash, terminal, linux-mint

Is there a command in the terminal to open a folder browser (Nautilus, Caja, etc) at the current directory? I.e.

```
~/very/long/path/ $ open-folder-command
```

opens a folder at `~/very/long/path/`

Or is there another easy alternative to it?

Comment: Other than `nautilus .`? Maybe you are looking for `xdg-open .` then?

Comment: Thanks, `xdg-open` did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use $PWD as Argument to Nautilus

This works fine for me. YMMV with other file managers.

```
mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/baz
cd /tmp/foo/bar/baz
nautilus "$PWD"
```

Comment: Thanks, works on Ubuntu. As @tripleee commented, `xdg-open` works in Linux Mint for me.